# Contextual Tokenizer that depends on the context in Transformer NLP

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, token, huggingface-transformers

I would like to create a tokenizer that tokenizes words in a sentence depending on its surroundings. So one word could have different tokens depending on its neighbor words. For example, if I have these two sentences: "Soccer is fun" and "She plays soccer really well". I would like to create a tokenizer that creates different tokens for the same word "soccer" because the surrounding words are different. Is doing such a tokenizer possible, and if somebody can direct me on how to do it (some links or resources)?

Comment: The tokenizer is usually just a simple algorithm that maps strings to ids. Contextualizing each id is done by a transformer. Can you explain what you want to do with a contextual tokenizer? That will maybe help people to answer your question.